# MATLAB: Easy way to multiplying standard basis

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

It seems to be easy, but I am not good at it.

I would like to generate the following matrix that is multiplying of two standard basis:

> $E_{ij}:= (e_i - e_j)(e_i - e_j)^T$

Could any body knows how to write it in few lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are dealing with standard basis elements that are orthonormal, then

```
e_i * e_j^T
```

is a sparse matrix with all but the `i,j`-th entry equals to zero.

So, if `ii` and `jj` are the indices of the two basis vectors and `n` is the dimension, then:

```
Eij = sparse( [ii ii jj jj], [ii jj ii jj], [1 -1 -1 1], n, n );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each vector from your basis is a matrix of size `d x N` (vectors arranged column-wise):

```
e1 = rand(4, 3); % random 4 x 3 matrix
e2 = rand(4, 3);
```

then each entry in your matrix, i.e. the inner product between two single vectors will be given by

```
E(i,j) = (e1(:,i) - e2(:,j))' *(e1(:,i) - e2(:,j));
```

The opposite would hold for `N x d` matrices, i.e.

```
E(i,j) = (e1(i,:) - e2(j,:)) * (e1(i,:) - e2(j,:))';
```

In the first case you can build the entire matrix by single one-liner:

```
E = (e1 - e2)' * (e1 - e2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the e's are all vectors that in i'th position is 1 and the other entries are all zero. They are not any more matrix.